# Error while trying to access a value from cursor

Tags: sql, plsql

Suppose a cursor named `cur(param_1 number,param_2 varchar2)` returns three value like bellow

```
place    name     value
pl1      mango    good
pl2      grapes   not good
pl3      apple    good
pl4      orange   very good
```

How to take each value individually from this cursor and do operations , like I want to take `pl1` and do this

```
for y in cur1(param_1,param_2) loop
if y.place='pl1' then
do this
elsif y.place='pl2' then
do this
else 
do this.
end if;
```

In my procedure am getting error saying

> error: 'pls-00364: loop index variable 'y' use is invalid'.

Any Suggestion?

Comment: Maybe he's a COBOL programmer!

Comment: haha dudes it's fixed lol thanks to http://www.string-functions.com/case.aspx ^^

Comment: hey all, i apologise for bad formatting. I was in a hurry thinking about the solution, guys help me out on this. thanks .

Comment: Honestly, this question has all the info needed to answer it. It is not vague. No need to close or downvote. **Instead, simply fix the title yourself if you are so offended by it**

Comment: check [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1907/referencing-pl-sql-variables-in-for-loop) and [here](http://iderror.com/errors/oracle/oracle-db/plsql-and-fips-messages-pls/pls-00364-loop-index-variable-string-use-is-invalid/) it might help you on getting a solution

Answer (score 1):

You are using the index value `y` inside the loop.

Something like this code [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48c88/20) should work, at least it works for me.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur(param_1 number,param_2 varchar2) IS
     SELECT place, name, value FROM product;

  auxCur cur%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
  FOR y IN cur(1,'2') LOOP
    IF auxCur.place = 'pl1' THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('1');
      ELSIF auxCur.place = 'pl2' THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('2');
      ELSE
        dbms_output.put_line('3');
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Hi @Yaroslav , When i did what you have shown above am getting an error saying **ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection**. Is there no need to do like **fetch cur into auxcur** or any other thing which initiliases the auxcur i guess , i need to initialise that auxcur, please help

Comment: Hi, I do not have an Oracle/Toad instance installed so my testing are all on the SQL Fiddle site. The `FOR LOOP` can work as an explicit or implicit cursor and on both cases no need to call the OPEN clause at all. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#BABGJBEA) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/static.htm#CIHCGJAD) for detailed information about the subject. Hope it helps.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183061/pl-sql-cursor-for-loop) too as example, it just does not have parameters to call the cursor.

Comment: Does your error has finally something to do with the code posted? if yes then please provide feedback to correct the answer.